# Exporting tables from MS Access to Snowflake via Docmd TransferDatabase

Tags: sql, odbc, export, ms-access-2010, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

DoCmdTransfer Database fails with Run-time error 3146
ODBC -call failed.
Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current schema. Call 'USE SCHEMA', or use a qualified name.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=ODBC32- 
AccessToSWF;UID=yyyy;PWD=xxxx;LANGUAGE=us_english;" & "DATABASE=test", 
acTable, "WB_EXP_OUT", "WB_EXP_OUT"
```

I was expecting to export table "WB_EXP_OUT" to Snowflake in the default schema of test database.
I was not expecting to be requested the schema and I don't know where to enter it in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the tool you are using uses the ODBC driver. 
Based on the title of you question, it looks like you are using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferdatabase with Visual Basic, are you using the DSN tool?

If so, I did find another user with this error that fixed it in this comment from Suzy. https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009LIzbGSAT/export-from-ms-access-to-snowflake-missing-pwd-error

> FrankBullit
>   3 months ago
>   @suzy...
>   I have an update on the docmd method: I think I have established the connection but it fails with Run-time error '3146' ODBC call failed.
>
> Cannot perform CREATE TABLE. This session does not have a current schema.
>
> Call 'USE SCHEMA' or use a qualified name.
>
> Here is the code, but I was unable to find a fix that works
>
> DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", "ODBC;DSN=ODBC32-AccessToSWF;UID=edifolco;PWD=xxxx;LANGUAGE=us_english;" & "DATABASE=test", acTable, "WB_EXP_OUT", "WB_EXP_OUT"
>
> Not sure you can really specify a Schema.
>
> suzy.lockwood
>   3 months ago
>
> Hi ... These are some very curious errors. Are you using either a system or user DSN via the Data Source Administration tool? The DSN needs to be configured and then it should have an associated entry in the registry where you can edit the additional parameters. The DSN can also have the schema or database parameters, or you can include in the registry entry as well.

Was that helpful?

Comment: Yes it was useful. I was able to perform the requested operation via changing values in the regirstry